# Bulk Update neo4j relationship properties through csv

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a csv file which have 3 column

```
Follower_id,Following_id,createTime
```

My Node in neo4j represent a USER and it has multiple properties one of them is `profileId`,.Two nodes in the graph can have `FOLLOW_RELATIONSHIP` and i have to update the createtime for `FOLLOW_RELATIONSHIP` properties.There are lots of relationships in the graph. I am new in neo4j i dont have much idea about how to do bulk update efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILEPATH' AS row
WITH row
MATCH (u1:User{profileId: row.Follower_id})
MATCH (u2:User{profileId: row.Following_id})
MERGE (u1)-[r:FOLLOW_RELATIONSHIP]->(u2)
SET r.createTime = row.createTime
```

`FILEPATH` is the path of the file on your system, usually within the database directory itself or some web link. You can learn how to set it from this [article](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file-containing-headers).